# What is a Java Universe?

Tags: java

Sorry for asking a basic question. I'm new to Java programming and I was learning  the core concepts of Java. I was reading access modifiers topic and I came across a sentence “methods, blocks declared inside a public class can be accessed from any class belonging to the Java Universe”. After reading this sentence, my assumption is that any program written in Java belongs to Java Universe. I'm not sure about my assumption and I searched on the internet to find out more about Java Universe.But I could not find anything. Please help me with this.

Comment: The vote to close because "this is about English" is a bit flippant. I could ask what a "volatile" field means, and you could say it's just a question about English -- but it's more than that, because `volatile` means something specific in Java. Without knowing the answer to this question, it's similarly plausible that "the Java Universe" is a similarly specific term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a technical term -- the author is being mildly poetic. Basically, what this means is that [public] methods in a public class can be accessed by any other Java class (as long as that other class is being executed in the same JVM as your class), even if it's not one that you wrote.

It's, for instance, why you can call `ArrayList.length()` even though it was written by Oracle, and even if you have absolutely no affiliation with Oracle.

Comment: Thanks for  all the answers. Can the down voter explain me what's wrong with my question.

Comment: @user123456 Not the downvoter, but this site is meant for questions and answers on specific programming problems (as opposed to florid prose). Please see the Stack Overflow [Help File](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for information on how to ask questions that are both on topic and useful. And thank you for your question -- it's off topic, but it made me laugh out loud.

Comment: Being new to Java programming I did not know that "Java Universe" was a general English term being used there. So, I clearly explained the situation and asked my doubt. I did not know why people down voted the question.Please provide a detailed  genuine explanation I will definitely accept the down votes.  Behaviors like this makes new users like me to leave stack overflow with a bad experience.

Comment: @MarsAtomic Your sentiment is clearly in the majority by the downvotes and close votes, but let me ask you: if you didn't know from experience that "Java Universe" is florid prose while "a Java bean" (or "Ruby gem", or any other number of fun terms) is something extremely specific, would you be able to identify the florid from the specific based on just those words? Especially given that the book apparently capitalized "Java Universe," it sure sounds like it could be a specific programming term. The fact that the answer is "it's not a real term" doesn't make the question invalid.

Comment: @MarsAtomic  Good that my question made you laugh.Thank you for your explanation.But How would I know being new to Java that " Java Universe " is a florid prose term?. I did find technical definitions being asked in stack overflow( not only programming).

Comment: @user123456 Don't take it personally -- it wasn't meant as such (from me, at any rate). If I were to downvote, it would be based on the non-programming nature of your question. You asked for a definition, rather than asking a specific programming question. In that context, whether I would think that a Java Bean was a metaphor or a technical term is irrelevant. SO is for programming questions and answers. Previous off topic questions may have misled you, but you are being informed here, and just because others err doesn't mean you should. You know better now.

Comment: @yshavit Whether "Java Universe" is a real term is not, nor  has it ever been, the issue (from my perspective). Post a question asking "What does HashMap mean?" and see whether it attracts downvotes. In contrast, ask why your use of HashMap does X when you expect Y and post the relevant code and I suspect you'll get some pretty constructive advice, as well as leaving behind a Q&A pairing that will benefit later readers.

Comment: @MarsAtomic Thank you.I did understand you now. I would be more specific in future. But " What does the Hash map mean?" may have explanation in google. I did check google before about Java Universe,then I posted the question. In future I would limit my question to a programming problem.

Answer (score 3):

The author is being painfully metaphorical. I believe it means any class that runs within the context of the same Java Virtual Machine has permission to access a `public` class. That includes Java, but also languages like Scala, Groovy and Clojure.